# Parse - Cannot merge AddUnique Op with the previous Op

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using Parse Cloud Code to create some objects in the Parse database. When I create an object, I first add some preset values and then want to store all unique elements of an array:

```
    if (bizStrategy != null) {
      person.add("biz", bizStrategy);
    }
    if (legal != null) {
      person.add("biz", legal);
    }
    if (financialConsulting != null) {
      person.add("biz", financialConsulting);
    }
    if (gettingStarted != null) {
      person.add("biz", gettingStarted);
    }
    if (hr != null) {
      person.add("biz", hr);
    }
    if (businessDev != null) {
      person.add("biz", businessDev);
    }
    if (careerAdvice != null) {
      person.add("biz", careerAdvice);
    }
    if (internationalDev != null) {
      person.add("biz", internationalDev);
    }
    if (otherBiz != null) {
      var bizArray = separateTags(otherBiz);
      for(var i=0, len=bizArray.length; i < len; i++){
        var skill = bizArray[i];
        person.addUnique("biz", skill);
      }
    }
```

However, I get the following error:
**"Cannot merge AddUnique Op with the previous Op"**

I tried looking it up, but it returns a single google result: [image]

I hope you can help!

EDIT: logs

```
  E2015-11-17T16:18:00.808Z]v246 Ran job standardisePeople with:
    Input: {}
    Result: Error: Cannot merge AddUnique Op with the previous Op
      at t.a.value (Parse.js:14:21539)
      at n.value (Parse.js:14:6067)
      at n.value (Parse.js:14:6551)
      at main.js:331:20
      at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:15:1692)
      at e.s (Parse.js:14:27156)
      at Parse.js:14:27542
      at i (Parse.js:14:27497)
      at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:27527)
      at Parse.js:15:1669
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your code. What other Operations are being applied to that`person` object in your code ??

Comment: I am doing a billion other operations. Basically, I'm adapting data from a csv with ~150 columns. Every operation is of either .add, .set or .addUnique type.

Comment: @MoNazemi: added the code immediately preceding the problematic part

Comment: The reason is that you are applying multiple `addUnique` operations in one update but they cannot be done because then uniqueness cannot be guaranteed. I suspect `addUnique` guarantees uniqueness by comparing a value you are adding with all the already saved values in the object not with all the values within an update

Comment: That makes sense. In the end, I'll probably handle it in 'beforeSave' instead